# Tryng to use and or queries

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, I have a table with six columns. A name and (let's say pets) so the columns are marked cat, dog, fish, rabbit and hamster. I want to do a query that I can check cat and it will show all the people with cats, check cat and dog and it will show all the people with a cat, a dog or both. Check cat dog and fish and it will show me everyone who has either a cat or a dog or a fish or both or all three. I can get it to show who has all three, but then it stops showing me who only has one of the pets. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will need three variables or objects if building in a language like c# to specify what you are searching for based on your check boxes.

```
Select * 
   From Pets 
   Where (CatChecked = 1 And 1Cat = 1) Or 
         (DogChecked = 1 And Dog = 1) Or 
         (FishChecked = 1 And Fish = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempts, but I guess this is just too far above my head. I don't know C# or SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Is this for a school project?  I'm going to assume it's for work but typically on this site everyone is very happy to help but I would suggest you add how you feel the query should look like, and ask where you're having an issue.  This way you'll get everyone involved and there's less likely of a chance to get your answer closed just to keep the site's answers very high quality.  This answer might be closed soon so please keep that in mind for the next one.  Thanks now on to your question.

There's not a lot of details to the question, I'm going to assume your columns are bool so it's either a 1 or a 0 to state if the name has that pet or not.

```
USE <DBNAME>
GO
SELECT Name 
FROM DBO.PETS
WHERE 
<INSERT COLUMN NAME OF PET HERE> = 1
--If you have multiple pets use the AND
AND
<INSERT COLUMN NAME OF 2ND PET HERE> = 1
```

You marked SQL in the tag so here is the ANSI92 compliant SQL for your question.

Comment: No, not for school. It is for work but I changed the sensitive information to pets. I created a table FilterValues form with the five buttons. When they are pressed, a query shows the listed "pets", but as I said, it will not show and/or, just if the name has all of the selected items. As far as SQL is concerned, I didn't mean to check it. I just know basic Access at this point. Still learning.

Comment: ah noted.  Ok.  I don't have a local machine with Access on it so I can't help at the moment but that query and the answer from Joe should get you on the right track.  Come back with your errors or something of the sort if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your attempts, but I guess this is just too far above my head. I don't know C# or SQL.

Comment: Check out Joe's answer, it should be helpful.  If you want google 'access sql queries' or something of the sort.  Or if you want to learn bare basic SQL syntax search for sql select basics.  Good luck